# regex to replace digits of a number with 0 (after 6th digit and before last 4th digit)

Tags: java

Need a regular expression
To replace digits of a number with '0' after 6th digit and before last 4 digits.
like

```
Input : 11111111111111     Output : 11111100001111
Input : 1234567878789999   Output : 1234560000009999
```

I tried regex:'`^([0-9]{6})([^0]+)([0-9]{4})$`' .

```
    int count = 0;
    String inputNumber = "1234567878789999";
    String convertedNum = "";
    Pattern pattrn = Pattern.compile("(\\d|\\D)");
    System.out.println(inputNumber);
    Matcher m = pattrn.matcher(inputNumber);

    while (m.find()) {
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("(\\d)");
        Matcher m1 = pattern1.matcher(m.group());
        if (m1.find()) {
            count++;
            if (count > 6 && count < inputNumber.length()-4){
                convertedNum = convertedNum +  m.group().replace(m.group(), "#");
            }else{
                convertedNum = convertedNum +m.group();
            }
        } else{
            convertedNum = convertedNum +m.group();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("convertedNum : "+ convertedNum);
```

Comment: please find regex for above requirement.

Comment: So the input has to contain at least eleven digits?

Comment: Simple java code will be easier for this

Comment: Hi Abra, yes, input will have at least eleven digits.

Comment: Hi Hades, want to replace with regex.

Comment: have you tried --- String replaceString=s1.replaceAll("[\\d]{6}(\\d+)[\\d]{4}","0");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num_string  = sc.nextLine();
    String patternString = "(?<=[0-9]{6})([0-9])(?=[0-9]{4})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(num_string);
    String answer = matcher.replaceAll("0");
    System.out.println(answer);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This one will give you what you want:

```java
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{6})(\\d+)(\\d{4})$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1234567878789999");

if (matcher.find()) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(matcher.group(1));
    for (int i = 0; i < matcher.group(2).length(); i++) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
    sb.append(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); //prints 1234560000009999
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel for your response.other than this can we directly use replace() method of Matcher class

Comment: @VikasGope, at least there's no I'm aware of.

Comment: Thank You Pavel Smirnov.